# AudioKit record all audio to file

Tags: ios, audiokit

Is there any relatively easy way to record *all* audio output when using AudioKit to a file? That is, instead of audio output going to the speaker it is recorded to disk.

Answer (score 0):

Just use `AKNodeRecorder`, easy. For some reason I thought this didn't pick up `AKSequencer` output.